# Nested if loop with DataFrame is very,very slow

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, dataframe

I have 10 million rows to go through and it will take many hours to process, I must be doing something wrong

I converted the names of my df variables for ease in typing

```
Close=df['Close']
eqId=df['eqId']
date=df['date']
IntDate=df['IntDate']
expiry=df['expiry']
delta=df['delta']
ivMid=df['ivMid']
conf=df['conf']
```

The below code works fine, just ungodly slow, any suggestions?

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
for i in range(2,1000):
if delta[i]==90:
    if delta[i-1]==50:
        if delta[i-2]==10:
            if expiry[i]==expiry[i-2]:
                df.Skew[i]=ivMid[i]-ivMid[i-2]

print(datetime.datetime.now().time())


14:02:11.014396
14:02:13.834275


df.head(100)
Close   eqId    date    IntDate expiry  delta   ivMid   conf    Skew
0   37.380005   7   2008-01-02  39447   1   50  0.3850  0.8663  
1   37.380005   7   2008-01-02  39447   1   90  0.5053  0.7876  
2   36.960007   7   2008-01-03  39448   1   50  0.3915  0.8597  
3   36.960007   7   2008-01-03  39448   1   90  0.5119  0.7438  
4   35.179993   7   2008-01-04  39449   1   50  0.4055  0.8454  
5   35.179993   7   2008-01-04  39449   1   90  0.5183  0.7736  
6   33.899994   7   2008-01-07  39452   1   50  0.4464  0.8400  
7   33.899994   7   2008-01-07  39452   1   90  0.5230  0.7514  
8   31.250000   7   2008-01-08  39453   1   10  0.4453  0.7086  
9   31.250000   7   2008-01-08  39453   1   50  0.4826  0.8246  
10  31.250000   7   2008-01-08  39453   1   90  0.5668  0.6474  0.1215
11  30.830002   7   2008-01-09  39454   1   10  0.4716  0.7186  
12  30.830002   7   2008-01-09  39454   1   50  0.4963  0.8479  
13  30.830002   7   2008-01-09  39454   1   90  0.5735  0.6704  0.1019
14  31.460007   7   2008-01-10  39455   1   10  0.4254  0.6737  
15  31.460007   7   2008-01-10  39455   1   50  0.4929  0.8218  
16  31.460007   7   2008-01-10  39455   1   90  0.5902  0.6411  0.1648
17  30.699997   7   2008-01-11  39456   1   10  0.4868  0.7183  
18  30.699997   7   2008-01-11  39456   1   50  0.4965  0.8411  
19  30.639999   7   2008-01-14  39459   1   10  0.5117  0.7620  
20  30.639999   7   2008-01-14  39459   1   50  0.4989  0.8804  
21  30.639999   7   2008-01-14  39459   1   90  0.5887  0.6845  0.077
22  29.309998   7   2008-01-15  39460   1   10  0.4956  0.7363  
23  29.309998   7   2008-01-15  39460   1   50  0.5054  0.8643  
24  30.080002   7   2008-01-16  39461   1   10  0.4983  0.6646
```

At this rate it will take 7.77 hrs to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the whole point of [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) & [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is to avoid loops like the plague, and do things in a vectorial way. As you noticed, without that, speed is gone.

Let's break your problem into steps.

**The Conditions**

Here, your your first condition can be written like this:

```
df.delta == 90
```

(Note how this compares the entire column at once. This is much much faster than your loop!).

and the second one can be written like this (using [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)):

```
df.delta.shift(1) == 50
```

The rest of your conditions are similar.

Note that to combine conditions, you need to use parentheses. So, the first two conditions, together, should be written as:

(df.delta == 90) & (df.delta.shift(1) == 50)

You should be able to now write an expression combining all your conditions. Let's call it `cond`, i.e.,

```
cond = (df.delta == 90) & (df.delta.shift(1) == 50) & ...
```

**The assignment**

To assign things to a new column, use

```
df['skew'] = ...
```

We just need to figure out what to put on the right-hand-sign

**The Right Hand Side**

Since we have `cond`, we can write the right-hand-side as

```
np.where(cond, df.ivMid - df.ivMid.shift(2), 0)
```

What this says is: when condition is true, take the second term; when it's not, take the third term (in this case I used 0, but do whatever you like).

---

By combining all of this, you should be able to write a very efficient version of your code.

Comment: Thank you Ami, for some reason the condition is always False cond=((df.delta==90) & (df.delta.shift(-1)==50) & (df.delta.shift(-2)==10)) but the data clearly shows that there shouls be cases where cond=True

Comment: You should try the sub-expressions interactively. In the Ipython console (or Notebook), type ``df.delta.head()``, then ``df.delta.shift(-1).head()``, then ``(df.delta.shift(-1) == 50).head()``, and so on.

Comment: (cont.) you have to get the pieces working starting at tiny chunks, then larger ones. I wouldn't advise that you do a multi-line op on 10M rows in one plop in any case.

Comment: not sure how to fix this but df.delta.dtype is int64 and df.delta.shift(-1).dtype is float64 therefore never having an exact value of 50 or 10.  I tried converting to int   cond=((delta==90) & int(delta.shift(-1))==50 & int(delta.shift(-2))==10)   but got an error message

Comment: Google "numpy.isclose".

Comment: Thanks again Ami, my newness to python must be quite obviouse by now.  I looked as "astype" and don't see me to see how to convert some of the values to int while leaving the rest (ivMid) for example as float

Comment: Two things: 1. you should google both "numpy.isclose" and "pandas.astype". 2. StackOverflow, at least to my understanding, isn't really built for a rolling-answer-dialog. I think the answer above basically addresses what you raised. It's very possible that you still have sub-problems. In this case, you should by all means ask *new* questions. Note that I can't even add code snippets to these comments - it's not built for that. This is really not an attempt to brush you off.

Comment: your suggestions seem spot on (new thread), never thought of abandoning this 1-to-1 chat and asking another question re:astype or isclose  it is obvious your a giving person or you would not have answered, all the best, John

Comment: just wanted to follow up, looks like shift(-1) should be shift(1) and shift(-2) should be shift(2)

Comment: Nice! Did you find it by printing the ``.head()`` of sub-expressions? I really think that's the way to work with this stuff. Will update the answer, BTW. Thanks.